# Canvas only drawing last element of loop on map

Tags: javascript, canvas, leaflet

I'm using Icon.Canvas to draw markers with canvas on a leaflet map. I'm having issues, which I am assuming has to do with "closure of loop" and yet I seem to be unable to use any of the other solutions due to the differences in creating a normal canvas and it's context and what I am doing (the canvas element and ctx are created by the Icon.Canvas library).

```
for (var park in parksMap) {

                var circle = new L.Icon.Canvas({
                    iconSize: new L.Point(50, 50)
                });


                var item = parksMap[park];
                var total = item.kpis.availability.online + item.kpis.availability.offline + item.kpis.availability.noComm;
                var greenSize = item.kpis.availability.online * 2 / total;
                var redSize = item.kpis.availability.offline * 2 / total;

                console.log('OUTSIDE');
                console.log(item);
                circle.draw = function (ctx, w, h) {
                    console.log('INSIDE');
                    console.log(item);

                    setUpParkForStatus(item, ctx, greenSize, redSize);
                    parkWindConstructor(ctx);

                    ctxArray.push({
                        id: item.id,
                        ctx: ctx
                    });
                } ... 

(code continues on to create the actual markers)
}
```

The setUpParksStatus is the function that has the actual code with the drawing. Following are results of the console.logs for a better understanding:

```
 OUTSIDE
 park1

 OUTSIDE
 park2

 INSIDE
 park2

 INSIDE
 park2
```

Comment: where do you save your draw?

Comment: Because you call that `circle.draw`  after the loop, and note that when you call it, the `item` is pointing to the last item in the loop.

Comment: @Saar Draw is a function from the library, so I'm not saving it anywhere. Should I be doing that considering on the first time around it doesn't even go into it?

Comment: @fuyushimoya The loop continues, it only finishes after the draw function is called. (note the brackets in the end of the code section)

Comment: I mean, when the `circle.draw` is called, it's already out of the loop(which supported by your log, inside is called after all outside called).

Comment: @fuyushimoya ah, yes I understand what you mean although I don't know how to avoid it doing so. In order to draw the canvas I need the information that comes from parksMap[park].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `IIFE` which returns a function that contains the current logic, so the value at the time won't be affect by loop.

EDIT: When step into `ES2015`, you can use the [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)/[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead of `var` to achieve with your current code, as its `block-scoped` instead of `function-scoped`.

If libs can be used [Underscore.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) can also do the work, if not, you still can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get keys as `Array`, then use `.forEach` to loop through it, all of these methods can prevent the value obtains in loop change with loop advancing.

Demo of Fail, and IIFE fix:

```js
'use strict';
var obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
};
var funcArr1 = [];
var funcArr2 = [];
var k, func1, func2;
for (k in obj) {
  // Way 1, all point to last.
  func1 = function() {
    console.log(k, obj[k]);
  };
  
  // Snapshot it
  // The wrap function will be called imediately, and it'll return the function similar to func1
  // But the outer function creates a scope, which stores the k(and rename it to v to avoid ambiguous)
  // So all the func2s will point to each key in obj instead of last.
  func2 = (function(v) {
    return function() {
      console.log(v, obj[v]);
    };
  })(k);
  
  funcArr1.push(func1);
  funcArr2.push(func2);
}

// IN ES2015, you can use let to achieve:
var funcArr3 = [];
var func3;
// The let, unlike var, is block scoped, so it can achieve what you expect in simpler form.
for (let m in obj) {
  func3 = function() {
    console.log(m, obj[m])
  }; 
  funcArr3.push(func3);
}

// To loop object with .forEach, which works on array.
var funcArr4 = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, index) {
  funcArr4.push(function() {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
  });
});

var i, length = funcArr1.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  console.log('Way1');
  funcArr1[i]();   // All of it will log c, 3, as k is pointing to c when exit the loop.
  console.log('Way2');
  funcArr2[i]()  // Because we use a function to keep k, it'll log what we expect.
  
  console.log('Way ES2015');
  funcArr3[i]();  // Because we use a function to keep k, it'll log what we expect.
  console.log('Way forEach');
  funcArr4[i]();  // Because we use a function to keep k, it'll log what we expect.
}
```

Demo with `forEach`:

```js
var obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
};
var funcArr = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, index) {
  funcArr.push(function() {
    console.log(key, obj[key]);
  });
});

var i, length = funcArr.length;
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
  console.log('Way forEach');
  funcArr[i]();  // Because we use a function to keep k, it'll log what we expect.
}
```

Demo with `let` of `ES2015`(This need some very modern broswer version for the snippet to work), but there's transpilers that able to compile ES2015 syntax to ES5 to work on most browsers(e.g: [babel](https://babeljs.io/)):

```js
'use strict';  // This make chrome to accept some ES2015 syntax
const obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3
};
// IN ES2015, you can use let to achieve:
let funcArr = [];
// The let, unlike var, is block scoped, so it can achieve what you expect in simpler form.
for (let m in obj) {
  funcArr.push(function() {
    console.log(m, obj[m])
  });
}

for (let i = 0, len = funcArr.length; i < len; ++i) { 
  console.log('Way ES2015');
  funcArr[i]();  // Because we use a function to keep k, it'll log what we expect.
}
```

So you can do the similar thing to your `circle.draw` :

```
// Now the current value that may be used by the callback won't change as loop advanced.
circle.draw = (function(item, total, greenSize, redSize) {
  return function (ctx, w, h) {
        console.log('INSIDE');
        console.log(item);

        setUpParkForStatus(item, ctx, greenSize, redSize);
        parkWindConstructor(ctx);

        ctxArray.push({
            id: item.id,
            ctx: ctx
        });
  };
})(item, total, greenSize, redSize);
```